Toric surface: How to approximate $\frac{(ax^2+by^2)^2}{x^2+y^2}$ into $a^2x^2 + b^2y^2$
My question is related to the approximation shown in the title. It appears in the process of calculating the sagitta $z=f(x,y)$ of a toric surface $(R_x,R_y)$.
Basically, the sagitta of a toric surface $z(x,y)$ can be approximated as follows:
$z(x,y) \approx \frac{x^2/R_x+y^2/R_y}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2/R_x^2-y^2/R_y^2}}$
However, if we calculate the sagitta in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ from its implicit equation:
$r^2+z^2-2zR(\theta)=0$
Assuming that the radius of curvature varies as the inverse of the Euler curvature, $R(\theta)=1/c(\theta)$, where $c(\theta)=c_x\cos^2(\theta)+c_y\sin^2(\theta)$, and transforming to Cartesian coordinates $(r^2=x^2+y^2, \cos^2(\theta)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}, \sin^2(\theta)=\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2})$, I arrive at the following result:
$z(x,y) = \frac{x^2/R_x+y^2/R_y}{1+\sqrt{1-(x^2/R_x+y^2/R_y)^2/(x^2+y^2)}}$
Which is very similar to the first expression, but the term in the denominator is different.
When I evaluate both terms, the differences are negligible; therefore:
$\frac{(x^2/R_x+y^2/R_y)^2}{x^2+y^2} \approx x^2/R_x^2+y^2/R_y^2$
The origin of this approximation comes from evaluating biconic surfaces when the asphericity in both principal meridians is null. However, I wanted to know if anyone knows what direct transformation or approximation relates both terms.
